# How to redirect to prefixed path in Expressjs Router

Tags: express

I am deploying an app in a specific path say under `/path`.

```
// login form
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
})
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  if (success) {
     res.redirect('/') // <<--- does not direct to /path
  }
})
// install router under path
app.use('/path', router)
```

So I can navigate to `http://.../path/login`
and after logged in, I want to redirect the user to the `/` under `/path`.

I don't want to hardcode `/path` and only use relative path since router has already been mounted under `path`.

Is it possible? How to do that?

Comment: Do you want the user to end up in `/` or in `/path` after the redirect?

Comment: I want to redirect to `/path`. But since I already specified that, I don't want to use the full path in all redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to redirect a user to the mount path (in this case, `/path`) without hardcoding it, you can use [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl):

```
res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/');
```

The `+ '/'` is optional for nested routers, but it's necessary for the application-level router because it has an empty `req.baseUrl`. Alternatively (if you don't want to add a trailing slash), you can use this (if you also want it to work in the application-level router):

```
res.redirect(req.baseUrl || '/');
```

Comment: This is sexy and useful!